# Duplicate Data from a column in one table to a column in another table multiple times SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have data in 2 tables as follows:

```
Table1
ID Quality
1  Q1
2  Q2
3  Q3

Table2
ID Quality 
1   
2   
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

I would like to update Table2 to be as follows:

```
Table2
ID  Quality 
1  Q1
2  Q2
3  Q3
4  Q1
5  Q2
6  Q3
7  Q1
8  Q2
9  Q3
```

I have checked a few answers on SO but seems I'm not getting it right when trying to use Cross join.

Comment: What happens if you are missing an ID on each table? What would be the expected outcome? We are assuming the link between your records but it would be great if you could explain the logic you want behind it. For example: if ID 3 didn't exist on table 2, would you like ID 4 to be Q3 or Q1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join using the modulus:

```
SELECT
    t2.ID,
    t1.Quality
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
    ON 1 + (t2.ID - 1) % 3 = t1.ID;
```

Note that we *don't* need to use `NULLIF` and `ISNULL` here.

If the second table might not have continuous IDs, but you still wanted to assign qualities using that general order, then we can try generating with `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) ID
    FROM Table2
)

SELECT
    t2.ID,
    t1.Quality
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN cte t2
    ON 1 + (t2.ID - 1) % 3 = t1.ID;
```

Comment: This will work perfectly if all IDs increment 1 by 1 and the op actually wants this distribution. The question isn't clear about this.

Comment: Not quite, `3%3=0`

Comment: @EzLo I addressed your concerns.  We can use `ROW_NUMBER` in this case.

Answer (score 2):

This get's you what you're after:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Table1 (ID int, Quality char(2))
INSERT INTO dbo.Table1 (ID,Quality)
VALUES(1,'Q1'),(2,'Q2'),(3,'Q3');
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table2 (ID int, Quality char(2));
INSERT INTO dbo.Table2 (ID)
VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9);
GO

UPDATE T2
SET T2.Quality = T1.Quality
FROM dbo.Table1 T1
     JOIN dbo.Table2 T2 ON T1.ID = ISNULL(NULLIF((T2.ID % 3),0),3);

SELECT *
FROM Table2;

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.Table2;
DROP TABLE dbo.Table1;
```

You need to use Modulus, but also cater for the 0's (as `3 % 3 = 0`).

Comment: You don't need to use `NULLIF` here, see my amended answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen +1 - 1 is very similar logic here. not sure it'll make any difference for performance, as the SARGability will be lost as soon as the modulus was introduced.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `NULLIF` (and thus the `ISNULL`) isn't required then @TimBiegeleisen , apart from if you're referring to use the `+1 -1` logic or performance? If I removed that, the answer would have the same flaw yours originally did. hence my assumption you were talking about performance. Perhaps you could elaborate please? Thanks. (As for the vote, it already had a vote from me).